# Alternative implementation to foreach using linq expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an array of keywords: splitKeywords  =  { "KeywordA","KeywordB","KeywordC" }

And the entity KeywordSearch:

```
public class KeywordSearch
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Keyword Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

Where Keyword is:

```
public class Keyword
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<KeywordSearch> KeywordSearches { get; set; }
}
```

How can I build an Array of KeywordIds based on ALL macthing KeywordSearch's ?

I have this very uggly code:

```
var keywordSearchQuery = _keywordSearchRepository.Query;

List<int> keywordIds = new List<int>();

foreach (var keyword in splitKeywords)
{
    var keywordsFound = keywordSearchQuery.Where(kws => kws.Name == keyword).Select(kws => kws.Keyword.Id);

    if (keywordsFound.Count() == 0)
    {
        keywordIds.Clear();
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        keywordIds.AddRange(keywordsFound);
    }
 }
```

I had this one but it returns ANY matching keyword:

```
keywordIds = keywordSearchQuery.Where(ks => splitKeywords.Contains(ks.Name)).Select(ks => ks.Keyword.Id);
```

EDIT:

Example:

```
KeywordSearch = { 1, "KEYWORDA", { 1, "KeywordA" }}, 
                { 2, "KEYWORDB", { 2, "KeywordB" }},
                { 3, "KEYWORDC", {3, "KeywordC" }}

 If I search for "KEYWORDA", I get KeywordId = 1
 If I search for "KEYWORDA KEYWORDB", I get KeywordId = 1,2
 If I search for "KEYWORDA KEYWORDX", I get NULL
```

Comment: How is `keywordSearchQuery` defined?

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's defined like this  "var keywordSearchQuery = _keywordSearchRepository.Query;"

Comment: What is `keywordSearchQuery`'s type?

Comment: It's type IQueryable<KeywordSearch>

Answer (score 1):

What you're conceptually doing is joining the two collections.

Anytime you're finding all items from one collection that mach the current item of a `foreach` loop you should look into a join, as that's probably what you're doing.

A Join is not only much cleaner, but quite a lot more efficient:

```
var query = from keywordSearch _keywordSearchRepository.Query
    join keyword in splitKeywords
    on keywordSearch.Name equals keyword
    select keywordSearch.Keyword.Id;

return query; //add a ToList here if it's important to materialize the query now
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but it's returning the keywords that contain ANY and not ALL that it's what I'm trying to achieve. If I don't find Keywords that match all KeywordSearch's, I have to return NULL

Comment: Has you can check in my code, if keywordsFound.Count() == 0 that means that a keyword was not found, I return NULL

Comment: @Patrick But if every single item matched a different key, but only one, then you're still returning each of those keys; you're not returning the keywords in all of the rows, so it wasn't doing what you're describing before either.

Comment: Sorry but I did not undestand what your are saying, I need to garanty that the search matches all the keywords, or else, it returns NULL. Mine is doing it I think at the moment.

Comment: @Patrick But it's not.  If all of the items match one keyword then none of them match all of the keywords, but your return all of them; additionally if several do match all keywords but some don't match any you return none, which is different still from what you've described.

Comment: One or more KeywordSearch's is related with a Keyword, but in the end, if there is at least one KeywordSearch not found in the KeywordSearch table, then I can't return any Keyword, because I have not in the DB table KeywordSearch records to match all the keywords

Comment: @Patrick but that's not what it's checking.  You're not ensuring each keyword is found at least once; you're ensuring every entry matches a keyword.  That's the reverse.

Comment: I'm trying to find a Keyword for each word in the splitKeywords array. If I find a matching KeywordSearch, then I have a Keyword. If there is only one word not matching any KeywordSearch, then I have no records that match all the splitKeywords.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it; it works with LINQ to Objects, I'm not sure how it will work when querying through EF.

```
var keywordIds = from keyword in _keywordRepository
where splitKeywords.Intersect(keyword.KeywordSearches.Select(kws => kws.Name))
                   .Count() == splitKeywords.Count
select keyword.Id;
```

Note that this query is based on a `_keywordRepository` instead of a `_keywordSearchRepository`. I thought it made more sense to structure the query that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Just to be more specific, each Keyword may have one or more KeywordSearch related with it, to have for example for the Keyword "Car", the keywordSearch's "CAR" and "CARS", and if I understand what your are saying, is that all keywords are in the KeywordSearch table for only one Keyword, and it's not the case here.

Comment: @Patrick I think I understand the 1-to-many relationship correctly. See my test data and see it run at http://ideone.com/slyWKr

Comment: Hi, I have check, but you are assuming that all keywordSearches are related to a keyword to be return this keyword, but it's not the case here. Each keyword like "KeywordA", "KeywordB", "KeywordC" has it's own keywordSearch "KEYWORDA", "KEYWORDB", "KEYWORDC", so if I search "KEYWORDA KEYWORDC" I will have 2 Keywords, but if I search "KEYWORDA KEYWORDX", I will got nothing, because I don't have Keywords that, trought KeywordSearch, match them all.

Comment: @Patrick your problem isn't clear to me. It would help if you edit your question to include example input and output data.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example, I hope it helps you.